# Dissolving polygon with enclave does not work

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-processing, dissolve

i tried to dissolve two polygons(brown and the yellow marked polygons) of one layer that own some en-/exclaves in QGIS (first union both, then dissolve the union-polygon).

But dissolving dose not work :(. I don't get an error but it dissolved only one polygon an the other one is not included.
There are also other polygons without enclaves and it works perfect.

The data I used is opendata (http://www.geodatenzentrum.de/geodaten/gdz_rahmen.gdz_div?gdz_spr=deu&gdz_akt_zeile=5&gdz_anz_zeile=1&gdz_unt_zeile=13&gdz_user_id=0, -> UTM32, Ebenen, ArcInfo-SHAPE). The polygons are NUTS DE124 and DE128 from file vg250_KRS.

Is there any way to dissolve these enclave-polygons with those other "normal" polygons in QGIS (I also tried the editor but it does not help)?

[image]

Comment: how did you do the disolve?

Comment: I first used union to create one polygon. Then I tried to dissolve this polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Premise: there is probably a typo in your original question since the features seem to be those having the `"NUTS"` field equals to `'DE121'` and `'DE124'`.

---

I firstly selected the two features of interest through a simple filtering expression:

```
"NUTS" = 'DE121' OR "NUTS" = 'DE124'
```

Then, I ran the **Save selected features** algorithm from the Processing Toolbox and I obtained a polygon containing two features:

[image]

Finally, I ran the **Dissolve** algorithm. If I leave the `Dissolve all (do not use fields)` checked, I can confirm your issue:

[image]

Instead, if I leave the `Dissolve all (do not use fields)` unchecked and choose any field storing a common value for both features (e.g. the "ADE" field), I get the expected result:

[image]